# android application not working with http://www.hostname.com

Tags: android, url

i've done an application in android which sends datas as parameters to remote mysql database using the following code with url as http://www.hostname.com.au/insert1.jsp as given below.

```
 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.hostname.com.au/insert1.jsp");
 String trackid= getIntent().getExtras().getString("param1");
 :
 :
```

but the above url did'nt works in some android mobiles
when i changed
**http://www.hostname.com.au/insert1.jsp**
to
 **http://hostname.com.au/insert1.jsp**
it seems working .

can anyone please tell me what's the reason behind this.

Comment: Does your server support wwww.hostname.com? if you are using linux or make type curl www.hostname.com and see what happens do the same with hostname.com 

Depending on the configuration of the server, www.hostname.com is not same as hostname.com

Comment: from your laptop, can you check by issuing the command in the console, 'curl www.hostname.com' & 'curl hostname.com'

Comment: The point is www.hostname.com is not same as hostname.com. If you want the client to use hostname.com the specify hostname.com and not www.hostname.com

some devices may be guessing the url by dropping the subdomain

You can install a windows version of curl and check it out the difference.

Comment: when i execute the command curl www.hostname.com' & 'curl hostname.com' i got an html content